# how to use mutexes with 2D vector

Tags: c++, pthreads, mutex

I have created a grid

[image: 2x5 Grid]

I have also created threads which can lock some areas of the grid.

[image: Locked areas are yellow]

How should I use the Mutexes so that any of the threads cannot lock an area which is already locked by another thread.

Can I use 2D pthread_mutex_t vector?

Comment: For one don't use pthreads, just use std::mutex, you might want differnet locking for reading/writing (std::shared_mutex). Probably you will need to embed the vector in a class of your own and do the locking from that (wrapper) class. (Usually it is not recommended to derive from standard library clases).

Comment: What is your "grid"? Mutex can be locked and unlocked, and the semantics of these operations is your choice. If you need atomic access to a vector (or matrix, or whatever) as a whole (e.g. if you want to modify its size), you protect the whole structure with your mutex, If you only need atomic access to particular elements, you should protect these elements, possibly with more than 1 mutex. Also, why do you want to use `pthread_mutex_t` if you write in C++?

Comment: Actually, this is a quite interesting question I once thought about (without a satisfying solution). A naive attempt might be to have a corresponding grid of `std::mutex` instances but I'm not sure whether this is a good solution nor it's performance impact. Another solution could be to manage a set of locked cells somehow. The access to this "set of locked cells" has to be mutex-guarded but with one mutex only. Then mutex-guarded part (the critical section) has to be the part where a thread aquires or releases a range of "locked cells".

Comment: This is going to depend on how you represent this in data. You could, for example, have a vector full of objects describing each region and containing a *mutex* to lock it. You would then have to collect all the mutexes from the regions that contain your cell and employ deadlock free locking on all of them.

Comment: To expand on the alternative offered by Scheff's Cat, that is my first thought on approaching the problem also. If you have a structure that is efficient to test and update non-intersecting regions, then you can control the blocking of threads using a condition variable along with the mutex.